# play video file java swing

Tags: java, swing, jmf

```
public void mediaPlayer(final String path, final JPanel panel) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Player p = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new  File(path).toURL());
                Component ctrlpanel = p.getControlPanelComponent();
                Component player = p.getVisualComponent();
                player.setBounds(10, 20, 300, 170);
                ctrlpanel.setBounds(10, 191, 300, 20);
                panel.add(player);

                panel.add(ctrlpanel);
                panel.repaint();
                p.start();
                System.out.println(" Player Started");
            } catch (NoPlayerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CannotRealizeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

I try the code play video file but get some error.

```
Unable to handle format: MPEG, 352x288, FrameRate=25.0, Length=152064
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@c7f314
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@c7f314
javax.media.CannotRealizeException
at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005)
at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:528)
at buffer.Action$1.run(Action.java:74)
```

Comment: do you have the correct codecs to play those videos installed??

Comment: JMF was abandoned years ago!  Better to look to use the Java-FX [`MediaPlayer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) instead.

Comment: thank you.Any examples or codes link to study.java swing

Comment: Tip: Add @TwelveDollar (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.